# How to convert linux command to c# | Open SSL

Tags: c#, linux, openssl

Hi I have a command running in linux.

How do I adapt this in c#??

```
signingString=X

signature=`printf %s "$signingString" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign "x.key" -passin "pass:changeit" | openssl base64 -A`
```

Comment: What is this command for?

Comment: To log into a web service I need to sign the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the openssl library into your c# project. Then do the similar  commands from c#. Both steps will take time.

First understand what each command does

- https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-dgst.html
- https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities

Then look at the openssl API, and learn what calls you would need to make to get similar functionality.

- https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API

Comment: Thank you for the information you provided.
I failed.
this is not a good enough answer for me